# Errors with subversion on NAS when using Windows

Tags: svn, nas

I have a NAS (Synology) and it is accessed via Windows. It works fine except for Subversion.

I get the same issues whether I use tortoiseSVN, svnadmin or visualSVN server and whether I access it via direct file access, http or svn protocols.

Simply, I can create a repository on my NAS and all files, etc. are created, but when I try and do something with it, e.g. create a folder, add a file, I get errors, all of the same format:

can't remove h:\SVN\db\txn-protorevs\7-9.rev: access is denied

I've also tried using full UNC paths with the same result.

When I ssh onto the NAS I can see that my user (which uses windows ACL) owns the repository files and folders and every file/folder has a full 777 mask.

I'd appreciate any pointers as this is doing my head in. My NAS works for any other file activity, it's just subversion.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the [steps in this wiki](http://forum.synology.com/wiki/index.php/Step-by-step_guide_to_installing_Subversion) to install Subversion on your NAS. I followed it and have SVN server up and running with no issues.